# Complex MySQL Query in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have information on NCAA athletes and where those athletes went to high school.  We would like to rank high schools by the number of NCAA athletes that attended said high school.

We have `players`, `teams`, `team_histories`, `accounts`, and `player_to_team_histories`.  An `account` represents a school (name, location, type (college, high school)), a `team` describes a particular team at an `account` (men's soccer, women's volleyball), a `team_history` represents one year of a particular `team` (the 2012 men's soccer team), a `player` represents the biographical information of an athlete (where they grew up, which high school they attended, their name), a `player_to_team_history` represents a `player` on a `team_history` (stats for the year, size, weight, position).

I've worked out the following MySQL query to extract the rankings for number of athletes from each high school at a particular college .  I'll break down the query below, starting with the inner most statements:

```
SELECT WrappedQuery.rank FROM
(SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank, q.Name, q.id
FROM    
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) counter, 
    (SELECT 
        Accounts.id, Accounts.Name, COUNT(Accounts.Name) AS count
    FROM
        player_to_team_histories
    INNER JOIN team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
    INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_histories.team_id
    INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = teams.account_id
    WHERE
        accounts.AccountTypeId = 1 AND player_id IN (SELECT 
            player_id
        FROM
            player_to_team_histories
        WHERE
            player_to_team_histories.not_valid IS NULL AND team_history_id = (SELECT 
                team_history_id
            FROM
                player_to_team_histories
            INNER JOIN team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
            WHERE
                player_to_team_histories.id = 574651))
    GROUP BY Accounts.Name
    ORDER BY count DESC) q) WrappedQuery
WHERE WrappedQuery.id = 7661
```

**Team History ID**

```
SELECT 
    team_history_id
FROM
    player_to_team_histories
        INNER JOIN
    team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
WHERE
    player_to_team_histories.id = 574651
```

This extracts the `team_history_id` for the college team we are interested in, which allows us to get the teammates for the player we selected (identified by player_to_team_history.id = 574651), because all teammates will have the same team_history_id.

**Teammates**

```
SELECT 
    player_id
FROM
    player_to_team_histories
WHERE
    player_to_team_histories.not_valid IS NULL AND team_history_id = (SELECT 
        team_history_id
    FROM
        player_to_team_histories
            INNER JOIN
        team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
    WHERE
        player_to_team_histories.id = 574651)
```

We use that team_history_id to get all of the teammates of the selected player.  We then use the players to find their high schools.

**High School Teams**

```
SELECT 
    Accounts.id, Accounts.Name, COUNT(Accounts.Name) AS count
FROM
    player_to_team_histories
        INNER JOIN
    team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
        INNER JOIN
    teams ON teams.id = team_histories.team_id
        INNER JOIN
    accounts ON accounts.id = teams.account_id
WHERE
    accounts.AccountTypeId = 1 AND player_id IN (SELECT 
        player_id
    FROM
        player_to_team_histories
    WHERE
        player_to_team_histories.not_valid IS NULL AND team_history_id = (SELECT 
            team_history_id
        FROM
            player_to_team_histories
                INNER JOIN
            team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
        WHERE
            player_to_team_histories.id = 574651))
GROUP BY Accounts.Name
ORDER BY count DESC
```

By grabbing the `player_to_team_history` associated with high schools (`accounts.AccountTypeId = 1`) for all players we are interested in, we can find out which high schools the teammates played at, group them by `accounts.id` and then sort by the count of each group, thereby giving us a sorted list of which high schools have the most players on the college roster.

**RANKING**

```
SELECT WrappedQuery.rank FROM
(SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank, q.Name, q.id
FROM    
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) counter, 
    (SELECT 
        Accounts.id, Accounts.Name, COUNT(Accounts.Name) AS count
    FROM
        player_to_team_histories
    INNER JOIN team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
    INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = team_histories.team_id
    INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = teams.account_id
    WHERE
        accounts.AccountTypeId = 1 AND player_id IN (SELECT 
            player_id
        FROM
            player_to_team_histories
        WHERE
            player_to_team_histories.not_valid IS NULL AND team_history_id = (SELECT 
                team_history_id
            FROM
                player_to_team_histories
            INNER JOIN team_histories ON team_histories.id = player_to_team_histories.team_history_id
            WHERE
                player_to_team_histories.id = 574651))
    GROUP BY Accounts.Name
    ORDER BY count DESC) q) WrappedQuery
WHERE WrappedQuery.id = 7661
```

We finish off by numbering each row of our ranking and grabbing the row we are interested in.  In this case, we are interested in the high school whose AccountId is 7661.  This is the high school the selected player attended, and this will give tell us, out of all the high schools that contributed players to the current college roster, where our selected players high school ranks.

**How to do this in Rails**

This is where I am lost.  How would I do these nested joins/sub queries and rankings of the results?

I totally understand this may be a terrible way to approach this problem.  Would it be better to break this into multiple queries and stitch everything together back in Rails?

Short of doing a `select_by_sql`, are there any places I can use Rails to make this easier?

**VERSIONS**

```
Rails 3.2.1
Ruby 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using AREL, but would require a lot of digging. But what I've used in the past to make subqueries a lot easier is to use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)

"Squeel lets you write your ActiveRecord queries with fewer strings, and more Ruby, by making the ARel awesomeness that lies beneath ActiveRecord more accessible."

Answer (score 0):

While this does not exactly answer your question, I would recommend you try this to solve your issue.

Take your existing SQL query and use an SQL template gem.

You can try something like [Yayql](https://github.com/gnarmis/yayql)
which is based on [Yesql](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql), but any text or SQL template engine will do.